# Changing layout of Org Chart subordinates in VBA does not work

Tags: vba, visio

In Visio 2019 Standard, I have an org chart that I have created using the Org Chart Wizard, and I would like to change the layout of the subordinates in the org chart via a macro. I have found some code that should do the trick (see below), but the line that should be changing the layout is not changing the layout at all.

From [this page](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26988890/Possible-to-automatically-Arrange-Subordinates-re-layout-Visio-2003-org-chart-shapes-in-the-Org-Chart-stencil.html) I found that I should add something like this in my macro:

```
Call visio.Application.Addons("OrgC11").Run("/toolbar_horiz1")
```

[This page](https://www.office-forums.com/threads/org-charts-auto-arrange-in-vba.1621640/) has something similar, but one of the poster's brought up a question about the version of Visio, and I'm not sure if that's relevant or not so I am including it here.

I am running a macro based on the code attached to the first page, and here's what the relevant portion looks like:

```
    For i = 1 To sel.Count
        Set shp = sel(i)
        If shp.CellExists("User.Solsh", False) Then
            If shp.Cells("User.Solsh").Formula = "{0BF98B35-200C-41D5-8A23-20EF77CBC94A}" Then
                If shp.Cells("User.ShapeType").ResultInt(visNoCast, False) = 1 Then     ' MANAGER
                    ActiveWindow.Select shp, visDeselectAll + visSelect

                    Call Visio.Application.Addons("OrgC11").Run("/toolbar_horiz1")

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: [Cross-post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=8898.msg39076#msg39076)

Comment: I'll check it out later, but you can just do `For each shp in selection` instead of the whole iterating...